# how to do fb login button and check if the user is member of group?

Tags: facebook

I made a Facebook login button and I want to check if the user is member of specific group. What do I need to do? This is what I am using but I want to check if the user is member of a specific group too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Login with Faceboo</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // FB App ID
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v3.3' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

    // Check whether the user already logged in
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //display user data
            getFbUserData();
        }
    });
};

// Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // Get and display the user profile data
            getFbUserData();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

// Fetch the user profile data from facebook
function getFbUserData(){
    FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture, groups'},
    function (response) {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogout()");
        document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = 'Logout from Facebook';
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
        document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '<p><b>FB ID:</b> '+response.id+'</p><p><b>Name:</b> '+response.first_name+' '+response.last_name+'</p><p><b>Email:</b> '+response.email+'</p><p><b>Gender:</b> '+response.gender+'</p><p><b>Groups:</b> '+response.user_groups+'</p><p><b>Locale:</b> '+response.locale+'</p><p><b>Picture:</b> <img src="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></p><p><b>FB Profile:</b> <a target="_blank" href="'+response.link+'">click to view profile</a></p>';

        // Save user data
        saveUserData(response);
    });
}

// Save user data to the database
function saveUserData(userData){
    $.post('userData.php', {oauth_provider:'facebook',userData: JSON.stringify(userData)}, function(data){ return true; });
}

// Logout from facebook
function fbLogout() {
    FB.logout(function() {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogin()");
        document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = '<img src="fblogin.png"/>';
        document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You have successfully logout from Facebook.';
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Display login status -->
<div id="status"></div>

<!-- Facebook login or logout button -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fbLogin()" id="fbLink"><img src="fblogin.png"/></a>

<!-- Display user profile data -->
<div id="userData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if that is still possible. The `members` edge of the `group` object has been removed a while ago, so at most you could find out via `/me/groups` - but the documentation says, _“[r]eturns a list of Groups where the User is a member and the User has granted the app any Group-level permissions for that Group.”_ I am not sure what exactly “granted the app any Group-level permissions for that Group” means, resp. how one would do that.

Comment: hey,thank you for your quick response..

i want to make a landing page that say "continue with facebook"
after the user click on this button, its working with the fb app.
after he give an access, i want to check if he member of this group

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: are you sure? maybe way to export group members??